# Why can't I trade TF2 items if I can trade Gmod items?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I'm trying to trade TF2 items with my friend, but it only lets me trade Gmod items, (Melon race, physics gun, etc). It says that I've been friends for only 12 days, is this a factor? If so, how long do I have to wait?

As a matter of fact, on the Steam app it says ALL my items are not tradable. Could this be a bug?

Answer (score 3):

**If you have not yet upgraded to Premium on TF2, then all the items you get are untradeable.** Chances are, the mobile thing isn't a bug.

If you want to upgrade to Premium, all you need to do is purchase an item on the Mann Co Store.

Comment: I believe there's a minimum spend of $5 for premium status - so if OP buys a key at $2.99 or whatever they're selling for it might not count (until another purchase is made)

Comment: Not necessarily. Any item can be bought off the store for the first time, regardless of its price, and that will grant Premium.